# SQL query to get all users not in group

Tags: sql

I have user and group tables set up as the following.

```
users
  id int

groups
  id int

users_groups
  user_id int
  group_id int
```

Example data:

```
+---------+----------+
| user_id | group_id |
+---------+----------+
| 1       | 1        |
| 1       | 2        |
| 2       | 1        |
| 3       | 2        |
| 3       | 3        |
| 4       | 1        |
| 4       | 2        |
| 5       | 2        |
+---------+----------+
```

Is there a way to select all users who are not in a given group? I tried joining the `users` and `users_groups` tables and adding a, say, `group_id != 1` condition, but I end up getting the user when they are in another group, e.g., users [1, 3, 3, 4, 5].

So when I say I want users who are not in a given group, `group_id != 1` in this case, the example results should be users [3, 5].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to select the id of the users **not in** a given group is to use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM users_groups WHERE group_id = 1)
```

Other commonly used alternatives are `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM users_groups
    WHERE group_id = 1
    AND user_id = users.id
)
```

And `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`:

```
SELECT id
FROM users
LEFT JOIN users_groups
ON users.id = users_groups.user_id
AND users_groups.group_id = 1
WHERE users_groups.user_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id 
  NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM users_groups WHERE group_id = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query like:

```
Select Users.* 
from Users 
where id in 
  (Select user_id from users_groups where group_id <> given_group_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.* FROM users AS a
LEFT JOIN users_groups AS b ON b.user_id=a.id
WHERE b.group_id!=1
GROUP BY a.id
```

The keyword is `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
 LEFT OUTER JOIN users_groups ug ON ug.user_id = u.user_id
    AND ug.group_id =1
WHERE ug.user_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd use a "WHERE NOT EXIST" statement in this case.